# OSCOLA BibLaTeX not recognizing repeated listing of author for co-authored works

Tags: biblatex

This question follows from a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211245/oscola-biblatex-not-recognizing-repeated-listing-of-author-in-bibliography). I am using the OSCOLA BibLaTeX style file. In the bibliography, when citing the same author more than once, the author's name should be replaced with a double em-dash. This works except when the author has co-authored works. In that case, the first author name is printed in full.

This is a minimal working example. First, a .bib file:

```
@phdthesis{Author2002,  Author = {Author, An},  School = {Department of Something, University College Somewhere},   Title = {A PhD thesis}, Year = {2002}}

@article{Author2003,    Author = {Author, An}, Journal = {Some Journal}, Number = {2}, Pages = {163}, Title = {An Article},Volume = {27}, Year = {2003}}

@incollection{Author2009,   Author = {Author, An},  Booktitle = {Some Book},    Publisher = {Some Publisher}, Title = {Book Chapter}, Year = {2009}}

@article{Author2013,    Author = {Author, An and AnotherAuthor, An},Journal = {Another Journal},Number = {1},Pages = {55--69},Title = {Another Journal Article},    Volume = {45}, Year = {2013}}
```

And the .tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=oscola,   ibidtracker=true,          backend=biber,       autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Test.bib}
% fixes a bug identified in a previous StackExchange question
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{thesis}{\printnames{author}}{\usebibmacro{author}}{}{} 
\title{Test Document}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 
First citation.\autocite[66]{Author2013}
Second citation.\autocite[31--2]{Author2002}
 Third citation.\autocite{Author2009} 
\printbibliography[nottype=commentary,nottype=jurisdiction,nottype=legislation,nottype=misc,nottype=legal]
\end{document}
```

The bibliography looks like this, at least on my system:

> Author A, ‘A PhD thesis’ (PhD thesis, Department of Something, University College Somewhere 2002).
>
> — ‘Book Chapter’, in Some Book (Some Publisher 2009).
>
> Author A and AnotherAuthor A, ‘Another Journal Article’ (2013) 45(1)
>   Another Journal 55.

The last reference listed should start with `— — and AnotherAuthor A`. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: It is reported that [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11138/with-biblatex-is-it-possible-to-replace-one-author-of-an-author-list-by-a-bibna) may solve your problem. If it does, tell us and this question will be closed. Otherwise tell us what is wrong.